# What's the difference between Prime Magic and Arcane Exaltation?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm looking at both of these prime spells, and they seem to do almost the same thing. The first claims to award 3 magic power to the hero, while the second claims to award 2 magic power *permanently*.

What does it mean by that? Is Prime Magic not permanent, thus having to be cast (or something)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC,

**Prime Magic** only awards the bonus to spells in the Prime spell tree (e.g. Implosion)

**Arcane Exaltation** works for all trees. So if you're a primary Dark Magic user, you can pick up Arcane Exaltation to increase the bonus for your Dark Magic spells.